# Unable to mount an hdd. Incorrect superblock?

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

**System**: Ubuntu 18.04

**Kind of disk**: internal hdd

My PC rebooted and now the secondary hdd has dissapeared. I tried to do: sudo mount /dev/sda/ hdd/, but it says:

> mount: /media/myuser/hdd: system file type incorrect, incorrect
>   option, incorrect superblock in /dev/sda, it lacks code page or the
>   auxiliar program, o either other error.

what happened? How can I mount it back? If I check with sudo fdisk -l I can see the primary sdd, lots of "/dev/loopN", where N refers to different ints (from 1 to 29) with small MiB quantities, and my dev/sda/ with the following info:

```
Disk/dev/sda: 3,7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logic/physic): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/best):4096 bytes / 4096 bytes 
Type of disk label: gpt
Disk identificator: 1ABCA8C7-4A1D-46E6-B676-1DDF7BBD3344
```

What are those dev/loop, btw? are they related to my error? A few days back the hdd was mounted and it was working well. I was entering remotely to this PC so I guess it rebooted due to some unknown case. Before mounting this one, I did the same with another hdd which was also unmounted and everything went smooth. Both are secondary hard drives and are typical 4TB hdd. But I see a difference in fdisk: the one that does not mount says that has a GPT table...

I also tried fsck:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck of util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (Mar-24-2018)
ext2fs_open2(): Incorrect magic number in the superblock
fsck.ext2: Incorrect superblock, it is trying to está intentando back the blocks...
fsck.ext2: Incorrect magic number in the superblock while it was trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock couldn't be read or does not describe a valid file system ext2/ext3/ext4.
If the drive is valid and really contains a system of files ext2/ext3/ext4
(and not one of exchange, ufs or other thing), then the superblock is corrupted; you could try to execute e2fsck with an alternative superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <drive>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <drive>

A partition table gpt in /dev/sda was found.
```

Comment: You cannot usually mount /dev/sda, you need to mount a partition. If it was not a system disk, most probably it is /dev/sda1. You can check which partitions exist using gparted or lsblk in the terminal.

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot! if you give me it in an answer i give you the solved tick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot usually mount /dev/sda, you need to mount a partition. If it was not a system disk, most probably it is /dev/sda1.

You can check which partitions exist on a drive using gparted or `lsblk` in the terminal.